# What are the opinions regarding eating small-bits-at-a-time ("leshiurin") on Tisha B'Av when necessary?

Tags: food, fast-days, health-safety-shmira, tisha-bav

I know on Yom Kippur, if someone is medically required to eat, s/he should do so with only a bit of food every few minutes, to avoid the full severity of eating "a full serving in one sitting."

On Tisha B'Av, does the same apply?  Or is it simply "if someone has to eat they have to eat, but it's a sad day, so don't gorge yourself on delicacies."

I think I've heard both opinions, can anyone confirm this, or identify who holds what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a machlokes.  Although the Biur Halacha 554:6 quotes the Pischei Olam that by a cholera epidemic a posek should advise to eat less than a Koseves bichdei achilas pras, that maybe because a) the asker isn't sick yet and b) otherwise the whole fast will be batel in the town (as the biur halacha says himself) (Shu"t Shevet haLevi 4:56). Nishmas Avraham also says the first svara in the name of R" Shlomo Zalman. Others who say shiurim don't apply:  Stimas Hamechaber [554:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.95), Aruch Hashulchan [554:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A7.D7.A0.D7.93_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96).  Shu"t Tzitz Eliezer quotes the Aruch Hashulchan (after suggesting that there are shiurim), and says you can be meikil but that one  who wants to be machmir and doesn't want to lose the fast, should eat shiurim.