# If you have problems fasting, what should you do on Tishá BeAv?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, health-safety-shmira, tisha-bav

Say that, **in every 24h fast**, you feel extremely nauseated, and then vomit at some point in the final 3 hours. What should you do during a fast like Tishá BeAv?

(Once I asked a Rabbi, and he said that eating according to *shiurim* is only permitted on Yom Kippur.)

Can you receive a *heter* not to fast, or to fast until some point in the day before the fast is over?

Comment: **CYLOR.** Each and every situation might be different.

Comment: It is not clear to me why your rabbi would say that Shi'urim is only permitted on Yom Kippur. Yom Kippur is a more serious fast, and Shi'urim is a way to get around the prohibition of eating while keeping someone healthy. The only thing I can think of is that the rabbi may have meant that if you need to eat Shi'urim, then you should just break the fast (whereas on Y"K that is not an option except in more serious cases). See my answer below, or just go ask your rabbi again (or a different rabbi who understands your problem better) - and your doctor.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2162/759

Comment: I have found my fasting much improved by weaning myself off caffeine at least a week before the fast.

Comment: This question is [too localized, asking about a particular case relevant to the asker](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/314). An attempt to generalize ti would render it a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2162. So I'm closing it.

Comment: @SethJ It's possible that since Yom Kipur is de'oraysa, you are allowed to eat in small measures, since the Torah never forbade it; however, the rabbis may have for Tish'ah B'Av since it is derabanan. I have no source, but that may be his rabbi's reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That person should be eating at some point in the last 3 hours if there's any risk that the nausea will affect their health (e.g. dehydrate).

The rules are:

1. Guarding one's health is more important than fasting. Always.
2. Fasting part of the day is better than not fasting at all. (E.g. children close to Bar/Bat Mitzva are expected to fast a few hours on Yom Kippour).
3. Shiurim is only relevant to Yom Kippour, and on any other fast once you should not be fasting then you can eat normally.
4. Those who are not fasting (children, and *unhealthy* people) should not indulge. Rather they should eat the minimum required - simple foods - to keep healthy. (I.e. Ice cream and bagels is probably not appropriate.)

Sources: Any classic sefer on the laws of Tisha beAv. E.g. Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 124:6

(Based on what I wrote [here](http://halocho.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/halocho-863-who-must-fast-on-9-bav.html).)

Answer (score 1):

> What should someone ... do...?

The correct answer is CYLORAMP = Consult Your Local Orthodox Rabbi And Medical Professional.

In short, this is a very serious health concern brought on by fasting. One should consult his rabbi **and his doctor**.

Asking on a forum such as this cannot provide a simple answer to a complex and personal problem.

Comment: Obviously consulting rabbi and doctors is necessary. Just wanted to know if someone, by answering more detailed, would know how to point sources for that kind of problems.